# Same result for  pk=request.user and pk=request.user.id in django

Tags: python, django

```
class MyUser(User):
    job = ...
    city = ....
```

`MyUser.objects.get(pk=request.user)` and `MyUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)` give me the same result. From [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/), pk must be an int. But request.user is an object. Why queries are the same for object and user id?

edit : I know that request.user is object but I want to know why results are same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is by design - if you pass a model object as the parameter to a query, it is the same as passing its primary key.

If this wasn't the behaviour, either passing the pk would be required, or an error, which would merely be annoying.

Thanks to rebus for this reference to the source: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L175

Comment: +1, [Source reference](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L175)

Comment: @Marcin, rebus, Thanks for anwsers.